# Angular2 - queryParam changes gets executed but not reflected in Safari + IE11

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, zonejs

I'm listening to queryParam changes in a component in order to update and save the state of an active row. Clicking on the rows highlights the one, using the browser back button marks the prev. row as active. So far so good. But then there's IE11 and Safari.

When I'm using the browser back button in IE 11 or Safari the code in my component get's executed, but not reflected in the DOM. When I run the changes inside the NgZone.run(callback) callback function, it get's reflected.

[Here's the Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/2sTW28Ql6Vq8GxtT22ne?p=preview) which reproduces the behaviour:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import {Router, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'list-component',
  styles: [`
    .isActive {
      background: gray;
    }
  `],
  template: `
    <div class="debuggerBox">
      Selected row index: {{ selectedIndex || 'none' }}
      <br>
      <div>Selected Item: {{ itemDetail | json }}</div>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let item of listData; let i = index"
          [class.isActive]="selectedIndex == item.index">
        <a [routerLink]="['/']" [queryParams]="{selectedIndex: item.index}">Index {{item.index}}, Name {{item.name}}</a><br>
      </li>
    </ul> 
  `,
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class ListComponent {
  listData: any = [
    {index: 0, name: 'Item #0'},
    {index: 1, name: 'Item #1'},
    {index: 2, name: 'Item #2'},
    {index: 3, name: 'Item #3'},
    {index: 4, name: 'Item #4'}
  ];

  selectedIndex: number;
  itemDetail: any = {};

  constructor(private http: Http, private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.routerState.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      if (params.hasOwnProperty('selectedIndex')) {
        console.log('queryParams.selectedIndex change detected');

        this.selectedIndex = params['selectedIndex'];
        this.loadItemDetail(this.selectedIndex);
      }
    });
  }

  loadItemDetail(index) {
    console.log('load item #' + index);
    this.itemDetail = {};
    this.itemDetail = this.listData[index];
    console.log('loaded item #' + index);
  }
}
```

Comment: There was a fix committed recently. I'd suggest you try again when RC.5 is out.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer do you know which commit? I want to dig into and understand the "why".

Comment: It's about zone and polyfills for eventhandlers that don't work properly with these browsers AFAIR. I'm currently only on my phone ...